# asp.net identity get all roles of logged in user

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, roles

I created a role based menu for which I followed [this](http://techbrij.com/role-based-menu-asp-net-mvc) tutorial. Some where down that page you'll see this line of code:

```
String[] roles = Roles.GetRolesForUser();
```

It returns all roles of the currently logged in user. I was wondering how to accomplish this with the new ASP.NET Identity system?

It's still pretty new and there is not much to find about it.

Comment: A great explanation of Claims and Identity for .NET Core : http://andrewlock.net/introduction-to-authentication-with-asp-net-core (not mine)

Comment: The selected answer is not entirely correct. See answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/63324519/2000301

Answer (score 152, accepted):

`Controller.User.Identity` is a `ClaimsIdentity`. You can get a list of roles by inspecting the claims...

```
var roles = ((ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity).Claims
                .Where(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Role)
                .Select(c => c.Value);
```

**--- update ---**

Breaking it down a bit more...

```
using System.Security.Claims;

// ........

var userIdentity = (ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity;
var claims = userIdentity.Claims;
var roleClaimType = userIdentity.RoleClaimType;
var roles = claims.Where(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Role).ToList();

// or...
var roles = claims.Where(c => c.Type == roleClaimType).ToList();
```

Comment: According to this doc http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.claims.claimtypes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx , there is no `Role` in `ClaimTypes`. Do I need to add it or something?

Comment: ASP.NET Identity uses `System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.claims.claimtypes(v=vs.110).aspx. Also, the `ClaimsIdentity` object also has a `RoleClaimType` property that contains the same value and you can use that instead.

Comment: Could you update your answer to show me how that will look like in code? Tried a few ways, but I don't see `RoleClaimType`.

Comment: Maybe it's just that things have changed in 2 years, but this doesn't seem to be correct. I just looked in my DB (tables created by EF), and there is a record in the AspNetUserRoles table, but no corresponding record in the AspNetUserClaims table, so Claims don't necessarily get added when a user is added to a Role.

Comment: (from c in ((ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity).Claims
                        where c.Type.Equals("role")
                        select c.Value).ToArray() //since asked for array

Comment: This answer would be great if it explained that ASP.NET Identity is **not** involved in this answer, only ASP.NET MVC

Comment: This answer is not entirely correct. Please see  https://stackoverflow.com/a/63324519/2000301

Answer (score 23):

Here's an extension method of the above solution.

```
    public static List<string> Roles(this ClaimsIdentity identity)
    {
        return identity.Claims
                       .Where(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Role)
                       .Select(c => c.Value)
                       .ToList();
    }
```

Comment: How to access it ?

Comment: This is an extension method off of the "System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity" object.

Answer (score 14):

After getting the Identity User from `SignInManager`, call `GetRolesAsync` on `UserManager` and pass identity user as parameter.

It will return a list of roles the identity user has enrolled in.

```
var rolesList = await userManager.GetRolesAsync(identityuser).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Comment: the selected answer is for claims not the answer for the OP which was asking for roles - this answers the OP

Answer (score 7):

I don't think any of the answers is entirely correct as they all take the principal identity of the logged in user. `User` is a `ClaimsPrincipal` and can have multiple identities (`ClaimsPrincipal.Identities` property). `ClaimsPrincipal.Identity` is the *principal identity* of those identities. So to get all roles of the user you need to get roles from all identities. This is what the built-in `ClaimPrincipal.IsInRole(string roleName)` method does i.e. it checks the given `roleName` exists in any of the identities.

So the correct way to get all roles is something like this:

```
    public static class ClaimsPrincipalExtensions

       public static IEnumerable<string> GetRoles(this ClaimsPrincipal principal)
        {
            return principal.Identities.SelectMany(i =>
            {
                return i.Claims
                    .Where(c => c.Type == i.RoleClaimType)
                    .Select(c => c.Value)
                    .ToList();
            });
        }
    }
```

and used as

```
var roles = User.GetRoles()
```

Also, note the use of claim type set in the identity `Identity.RoleClaimType` instead of the static claim type `ClaimTypes.Role` . This is needed because the role claim type can be overridden per identity e.g. when identity is received via a JWT token which provides ability to use a custom claim name as the role claim type.

Comment: 3 years later and this worked perfectly for passing IPrincipal to a custom auth method

Answer (score 4):

Don't use @using System.IdentityModel.Claims namespace, Instead of that use

> @using System.Security.Claims

```
    @using System.Security.Claims
    @using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity
    @{      
       var claimsIdentity = User.Identity as System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity;
       var customUserClaim = claimsIdentity != null ? claimsIdentity.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == "cutomType") : null;
       var customTypeValue= customUserClaim != null ? customUserClaim .Value : User.Identity.GetUserName();
       var roleOfUser = claimsIdentity != null ? claimsIdentity.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == ClaimTypes.Role).Value :"User";

}
```

Comment: What is this supposed to answer? Who is using `System.IdentityModel.Claims` and where?

Answer (score 0):

try below:

```
var roles = user.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Role).Select(x => x.Value).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use such syntax:

```
var userClaims = User.Identity as System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity;
var roles = userClaims.FindAll("http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role").ToList();
```