# how do I validate a token generated with asp.net identity on a asmx service

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity

net identity service which returns a token Bearer which I can validate really easy with the authorize attribute. Now my question is how can I validate this token bearer on other.net technology lets say an asmx web service?

basically, I want to decrypt the token to validate it on other services

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after some weeks of research the easiest way I have found is to make a call the wcf methods to a controller of the rest api. I got the idea from this post

[asp.net identity get all roles of logged in user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21688928/asp-net-identity-get-all-roles-of-logged-in-user?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)