# How to get the [Authorize(Roles = "RoleName")] into variable?

Tags: asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, authorize-attribute

i am trying to save the role from the AuthorizeAttribute in a variable but i cant seem to figure out how. i want something like this. Note: the User/Roles is created from Azure Active Directory

```
private string CalculateRole()
{
   var role = authorize.role; 
   return role;
}
```

i searched all over and "closest" i got is this question [asp.net identity get all roles of logged in user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21688928/asp-net-identity-get-all-roles-of-logged-in-user/63324519#63324519)

but all i get back is a list of Claims I cant find any "roles".

Comment: A "role" is just syntactic sugar for a particular type of claim. The answer you linked in your question is correct.

Comment: thank you, i figured it out, didnt understand that the roles where a type of claim  -_- but thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[Authorize(Roles = "RoleName")]` is used for access. We can specify the roles that have access to the requested resource using the Roles property of Authorize attribute. For example, `[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]` allows us to access the action method to users who are member of "Admin" role.

For the currently signed in user for an application, you can always find the [Application Roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/multitenant-identity/app-roles) assigned to them from the [**Role claims**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens#payload-claims) available as part of the access token from Azure Active Directory.

[image]

For more information, here's a [sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/5-WebApp-AuthZ/5-1-Roles) that uses OpenID Connect to sign-in users and use Azure AD Application Roles (app roles) for authorization. Also, you could use [Microsoft Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-approleassignments?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) to get the roles.

Answer (score 0):

You can get roles from db by current user id.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a bool validation within the Controller (where HttpContext.User e

```
bool isAdminUser = User.IsInRole("Admin");
```

This is fine if you want to validate for specific -or a few- Roles defined. If you have many roles this may not be the best option and you might want to consider to call GraphApi instead for membership validation.